# Microservices integration with WSO2

Tags: wso2-api-manager

How can I import my microservices(REST) in `WSO2` API manager, given I do not have swagger definition file?

I have microservices project built on spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

Without the swagger you will have to create api resources in api manager to match your microservice resources. You can refer step 6 of document [1] to add reources

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Create+and+Publish+an+API